# Concurrent processing of queue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, image, concurrency, queue

I am writing a small program to perform operations on pictures concurrently.

The idea is to have the program process command-line input and then perform the operations on different threads. For example, if the user wants to load 5 pictures into the program, then the loads will happen in parallel. The same applies to operations. At the same time as one image is loaded, another could be blurred and another could be rotated.

Right now I have the following structure:

```
--Main.cpp
--Picture.h
--Tools.h
--Event.h
--ConcurrentQueue.h
```

For each command (input) I create an event that is stored in the queue. Then a number of worker threads check the queue and execute each event.

One problem that seems to occur is that operations on the same image can happen at the same time (if one command is "resize img1" and the next is "crop img1"), and I want to avoid that (operations on the same image should happen in order).

Also, if I create for example 10 worker threads, it seems that each thread processes only one event of the queue, instead of continually polling (only 10 events happen).

This is a simplified version of the worker function that gets passed to the thread constructor:

```
void work(Tools *lib) {
  if (lib == nullptr) {
    cerr << "lib is null";
    exit(1);
  }
  std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
  cout << "Work function entered by thread " << this_id << endl;
  while (!finished.load()) {
    Event item = event_queue.pop();
    if (item.isEventA()) {
      lib->lock_picture(filename);
      /* 
      Do picture work here
      */
      lib->unlock_picture(filename);
    } else {
      lib->lock_picture(filename);
      /* 
      Do picture work here
      */
      lib->unlock_picture(filename);
    }
  }
}
```

`Tools` is the class that manages the transformations. In `Picture` I have a mutex and two functions

```
void Picture::lock() {
    picture_mutex.lock();
}

void Picture::unlock() {
    picture_mutex.unlock();
}
```

These are called from the `Tools` functions `lock_picture` and `unlock_picture`.

The `Queue` is a thread-safe implementation. I am using a global variable `finished` to signal the threads to stop working (although this doesn't seem to work at the moment).

Any ideas on improvements are welcome!

Comment: You don't seem to have an actual problem. If you want people to look over your code and give you a review, please head over to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Make sure to read their [help on good questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Answer (score 0):

You should forget queue/mutex and so on and switch to asio, the [asio::strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) class provides serialised execution, that is what you are looking for.

```
struct Picture
{
    asio::strand _strand;
    std::string _file_name;

    Picture(asio::io_service&);
    void Work1();
    void Work2();
    void Work3();
};

void main( bla bla bla)
{
    asio::io_service io_service;
    vector<Picture> Pictures(bla bla bla);
    for_each(Pictures.begin(), Pictures.end, [](auto& elt){
       elt._wrap.post([elt](){elt.Work1();});
       elt._wrap.post([elt](){elt.Work2();});
       elt._wrap.post([elt](){elt.Work3();}));

    // Create a pool of threads to run all of the io_services.
    std::vector<shared_ptr<thread> > threads;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    threads.push_back( make_shared<thread>(
       [&io_service]() {io_service.run(); }));
    // Wait for all threads in the pool to exit.
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i)
       threads[i]->join();
}
```

asio is available as [standalone](http://think-async.com/Asio) or as a [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Enjoy !